# Is this call to a function object inlined?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction, inline

In the following code, `Foo::add` calls a function via a function object:

```
struct Plus {
  inline int operator()(int x, int y) const {
    return x + y;
  }
};

template<class Fct>
struct Foo {
  Fct fct;
  Foo(Fct f) : fct(f) {}
  inline int add(int x, int y) {
    return fct(x,y); // same efficiency adding directly?
  }  
};
```

Is this the same efficiency as calling `x+y` directly in `Foo::add`? In other words, does the compiler typically directly replace `fct(x,y)` with the actual call, inlining the code, when compiling with optimizations enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For g++ 4.4.1, it will inline at -O1 or above.

I used the program (as well as your code):

```
int main()
{
    Foo<Plus> foo((Plus()));
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    int x = foo.add(a, b);
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

For -O0, you get (g++ -S, excerpted):

```
main:
.LFB960:
        ; ...
    call    _ZN3FooI4PlusEC1ES0_
    ; ...
    call    _ZN3FooI4PlusE3addEii
    ; ...

_ZN3FooI4PlusE3addEii:
        ; ...
    call    _ZNK4PlusclEii
        ; ...

ZNK4PlusclEii:
    ; ...
    ; This is the actual add
    leal    (%edx,%eax), %eax
    ; ...
```

At -O1 or -O2, Foo and Plus disappear entirely from this test.

```
main:
    ; ...
    addl    24(%esp), %eax
    ; ...
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, it depends on your compiler. If it decides to inline, it will inline. If it decided not to, it won't inline. Inlining is controlled by compiler-specific heuristics. It depends on the compiler. It depends on the compiler settings. It depends on the context.

The only way to say for sure is to try and see what happens. "Typically", it should be inlined.

P.S. Keyword `inline` is redundant when the function is defined in class definition. Such functions are inline already. Adding the explicit `inline` keyword makes absolutely no difference.